# RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I got this when I was using Hive Database in Flutter.
Find out answer below

Comment: hii, if you already have found the answer then can you please update it here?

Comment: Accidentally answer was deleted

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error. when I was trying to add data into hive database using `putAt()`, but from documantion i found out that `putAt()` can only be used for the existing index. so switch `putAt()`  instruction with `add()`. That solved the error.

I know the question is old, but I hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 6):

problem for me was, I am accessing the empty list with index.

ex:

`list=[ ] //this is empty list`

`list[0] // error, because I am accessing empty list.`

Answer (score 0):

So whenever you get this kind of Error!

Check if whatever you are saving in Hive Database is not null.
I got this error while I was storing null object to database.

Answer (score 0):

you should give and initializer for example if you want to give and array you should set a default value for example :

```
List<dynamic> _users = [];
```

this return error

but if you do this your problem will be solve :

```
List<dynamic> _users = [
 {
  "id":"",
  "name:"",
  "Phone:""
 }
]
```

depends of your data that fields